# Fatal CLR Error 80004005

Tags: clr

Today, everytime I try to open any **.Net application** I get:

```
CLR error: 80004005
The program will now terminate.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd start with [downloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx) and re-installing the .NET framework.

Comment: I ran the installer in "repair" mode, and it seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks! Unfortunately, I am still confused to how the FX was corrupted... oh well.

Comment: Other responses mention permissions issues, so maybe the "repair" mode simply re-set the necessary file/OS permissions for you. In any case, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and uninstalling/reinstalling dot net didn't help.

Randomly I found a suggestion to go to
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\

Then rename the directory called "Assembly" to "Assembly2" or something so you don't erase it but dot net will think it's gone.

After doing that, install dot net again.

This took hours for me to find and was the ONLY thing that worked.

Comment: Very interesting! 4.5 years later!

Comment: YESSS! FINALLY! This worked for me and nothing else suggested anywhere else. 4.5 years later but the bug is still present. Microsoft cultivates update-once-a-5-or-more-years development cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I believe 0x80004005 is (usually) an ACCESS DENIED error - so start with that in mind. If you're on Vista+, try running it as admin. Otherwise, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) should help you track it down.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search suggests this:

> "If you get a Run-time error 80131522
>   "No Server registered or could not
>   load class for CLSID ...", it is
>   because you are trying to run the VB
>   executable from a directory other than
>   where the .NET assembly is located.
>   This also happens if you try to run
>   the vb code in interactive mode. This
>   can be solved by installing the .NET
>   assembly into the global application
>   cache"

(http://bytes.com/forum/thread353655.html)

In an ASP.NET context, it appears this is related to file permissions:

> The error code for the failure is
>   80004005. This error can be caused when the worker process account has
>   insufficient rights to read the .NET
>   Framework files. Please ensure

(http://weblogs.asp.net/jambrose/archive/2004/09/01/224226.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but how is 80131522 related to 80004005??

Answer (score 0):

@MarkBracket: I had a similar issue, but I think I finally fixed it thanks to Process Monitor.

My Solution:
Go to "C:\Windows" and right click on the "Microsoft.NET" folder and click Properties.
Click the "Security" Tab, then click the "Advanced" button.
Click the "Owner" Tab, then click the "Edit..." button.
Select your current user account, then check the box that says "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" and then click "Ok".

Problem solved (for now at least). 
As it turns out, the programs simply didn't have the proper permissions needed to run.

Anyways, Thanks Again Mark
I hope this post is helpful to any and all who have/get the CLR 80004005 error.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to answer this from development prospective, as I got into such problem and solved it.

The problem I had encountered was that I was deploying a WPF application on a none development machine, It crashed immediately with the message "Fatal CLR Error 80004005".

I realized that I compiled my application as .Net framework 4.5 and I was using an API call from  System.Web namespace.

I solved it by changing the method call and then re-compiled it as .Net framework 4.0 Client Profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error pop up when I had a lot of other applications running.  Closing some of the more memory-intensive programs caused the error to go away.