# Visual Studio doesn't open - CLR Error 80004005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been using Unity and Visual Studio daily for long time without any problem. Today i open the computer (windows 10) and try to open Visual Studio but it doesn't open, and also when i try to open some apps like Discord or Razer Synapse i get CLR Error 80004005. I guess it has something to do with .Net Framework. I tried reinstalling it, repairing it and nothing works. Can someone help me, i have no clue what to do to fix it.

Comment: Try the [solution presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801700/2592875).  Or possibly one of the others in that question.

Comment: I think 80004005 means "access denied". Is some resource/file on your system in use or otherwise unavailable?